# Passing report parameter in Salesforce1?

Tags: javascript, parameters, google-charts

We have a google chart on our Engagement__c object, that is written to run a report on click with a passed parameter.  This works perfectly in the **browser**.  However, when clicking the link while in SF1, the report finds no data.  I assume it has to do with how to correctly pass the record id parameter to the SF1 version of the report.  But heck if I know what I'm doing wrong.

(section of code that determines the device and the URL calls)

```
if((typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
     if (party == 'Initial Contact'){
          sforce.one.navigateToURL ('https://company--pocpartial.cs22.my.salesforce.com/{!$label.report1}?pv0={!Engagement__c.Id}');
          }
     }
     else {              
          if (party == 'Initial Contact'){
               window.open ('https://company--pocpartial.cs22.my.salesforce.com/{!$label.report1}?pv0={!Engagement__c.Id}');
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing parameters to standard pages (including Reports) is not yet possible in Salesforce1.

To get around this, at present, you'd need to create the Reports/Charts using Visualforce. (Visualforce pages can accept parameters.) 
Here's a reference for Charting with Visualforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting.htm

There's an Idea on the Idea Exchange you can vote on as well, to encourage the Product Team to support parameters on standard pages:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjkfAAC