# Issue while navigating to standard report in Salesforce 1 App by passing parameters

Tags: javascript, reporting, parameters

I am trying to navigate to the standard report from a inline visualforce via javascript, on click of link, by passing the required parameters, as below :

for classic :

```
https://na1.salesforce.com/00O7A000000PDC9?pv0="+'{!startDate}'+"&pv1="+'{!endDate}'+"&pv2="+'{!filterVal}'
```

for lightning experience/sf1

```
https://na1.salesforce.com/one/one.app?source=aloha#/sObject/00O7A000000PDW9UAO/view?a:t=1490702197658"+"&fv0="+'{!startDateLast2Year}'+"&fv1="+'{!endDateLast2Year}'+"&fv2="+'{!filterVal}';
```

I am using `window.open()` for classic and `sforce.one.navigateToURL()` for lightning/sf1

This works in classic and desktop lightning experience and i am able to navigate to the standard report. However, it doesn't work in Salesforce 1 app. In android it is throwing :

> An error has occurred. Please try again.

In iOS it's navigating to an empty report with the message saying no data to view.

Is this a limitation in Salesforce 1 ? Is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: May be [this will help](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126610/passing-report-parameter-in-salesforce1).

Comment: Yes. This seems to be limitation in SF1